# Finding the center of 1D data

Tags: c, curve-fitting, gsl

Say I have data: `0 (or near 0), 0, 0, ..., 1, 10, 52, 80, 100, 100, 100, 100 (for a while), 90, 45, 5, 0, 0, 0...`
I want to find the index (not necessarily an int, I want more precision) of the 'center' of my plateau of data.

My first thought was to do a gaussian fit, but the data is rather flat for a while in the center. So maybe some kind of square (?) fit. I've been looking at minimization with gsl also, but I don't know what the simplest way to do this would be.

A simple way would be to find the index corresponding to the median value, but that gives me only a precision of 1. With a curve fitting I can do better.

Note: I'm in C and can use GSL, but a general math solution would work too!

Comment: If you plan to use this data a lot, then maybe sort it first. After which you can simply grab item number n/2 in the sorted array with size n and get the median.

Comment: Not precise enough I guess. But I just thought I could simply compute the center of gravity of the data...

Comment: Could you define 'center of plateau of data', specify the required precision, and how large the plateau is relative to both slopes?

Comment: `0 (or near 0),` - What does that mean?  If these values are integers, `0` is just `0`.  Is there some other type you are talking about to get _extra_ precision?

Comment: Plateau is 'a few times' larger than the slopes (1 to 3 times). Data is not integer, and as measurements go there is always some noise.

Comment: Are you looking for the centroid of an array?  It is the closest thing I can find to what it sounds like you are asking for...

Comment: Centroid is the same as the center of gravity, right ? In that case I guess so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested algorithm:

1. Optionally filter data: median of 3, low pass, etc.
2. Find average value: `Avg`
3. Find average index of values above `Avg`: `Center_index`.
4. Average a few of the "values above" near `Center_index`.

Answer (score 0):

[Weighted Mean Center](https://glenbambrick.com/tag/weighted-mean-center/) of a line, with an array similar to your data:

```
int w[] = {0, 0, 0, 1, 10, 52, 80, 100, 100, 100, 100, 90, 45, 5, 0, 0}
```

> ...is calculated by multiplying the x and y coordinate by the weight
> for that feature and summing all for both x and y individually, and
> then dividing this by the sum of all the weights.

Because this is a 1D array, position is expressed using the position within the array, i.e. the index,   and looks like this:

```
weighted mean center = sum(w[i]*i)/sum(w[i])  //for all i
```

in pseudo code:

```
double sum_w=0;//sum of all values (weights)
double prod_wx=0;//product of all corresponding weights and positions
double wmc=0; //weighted mean center
for(int i=0;i<sizeof(w)/sizeof(w[0]);i++)
{
    prod_wx += w[i]*i;
    sum_w += w[i];
}
wmc = prod_wx/sum_w;
```